Вывести видео в Google Colab
подскажите, как мне вывести видео в Google Colab (задача lunar lander, обучение с подкреплением)?
model = PPO(
policy = 'MlpPolicy',
env = env,
n_steps = 1024,
batch_size = 64,
n_epochs = 4,
gamma = 0.999,
gae_lambda = 0.98,
ent_coef = 0.01,
verbose=1)

